# Remove old phone number from iPhone

Tags: iphone, apple-id, cellular-carriers

I had a temporary number for a day after transferring to a new provider. My correct number has now been transferred to the new SIM. The settings, however, now contains both numbers.

[image]

The second number, with the unavailable message, is the temporary I now want rid of. Going into Edit only allows for removal of the AppleID xxx@me.com. The phone numbers just have an unhelpful ⓘ symbol, with this message

[image]

The number, of course, no longer exists - yet it will likely be recycled in future by the provider, so I don't want the association with this phone to still remain.

There are similar questions regarding removing a phone number from iMessage & FaceTime. That part was easy. They have correctly been re-associated with the 'proper' number [basically by switching it all off & on again.].

The temporary number has no association with Apple or iCloud at all. It shows nowhere but in here. Does anyone have a method to delete it? My google-fu is usually pretty good, but all I can find are methods to change the FaceTime & Messages numbers - already done.

Comment: When you say it has "no association with Apple" you mean that it doesn't appear on appleid.apple.com?

Comment: And you can confirm these numbers don't show up in the iMessage or FaceTime screens on this device (I think you said as much, but wanted to confirm for sure)

Comment: It appears nowhere but the Settings > [My Name] > Name, Phone numbers, Email section as in the photo. It was nothing but a placeholder number waiting for the 'real' number to be transferred between providers. FT & iM *did* automatically associate, but these have now been cleared completely, back to the correct number.

Comment: BTW, everything now *works* just fine. There's just this stray number hanging around that a) I don't want or need & b) doesn't even actually exist at the moment.

Comment: I suspect this'll either drop-off with time, or you need to call Apple to get it removed. They will probably be able to identify why it's sticking to your account.

Comment: @Ezekiel - it did, in fact, just fall off after a while. I put it in an answer for sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted in comments - eventually it just fell off, vanished.
Problem solved… by doing nothing at all.

[image]